# Backbone.js extend and this

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using experimenting with [.extend()](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-extend) to set up my views and initialise them with. I've found it's convenient to assign config variables to view objects nested deep within a hierarchy.

My problem is that my Views lose their *this* context. This becomes the *ctor* object which I asume is the constructor. How can I fix this?

My coffeescript is below. The first class would be nested deep within a tree, the second is at the top level where the application boots up:

```
# This is a child somewhere deep within a tree of views.
class View extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    console.log @ # returns object ctor

MyView = View.extend({
  initialize: ->
    # do config stuff then init prototype
    App.Views.MyView.prototype.initialize()
})

view = new MyView
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

First, and not as importantly, you can use

```
class MyView extends View
```

instead of `View.extend`. CoffeeScript classes and Backbone classes are interoperable.

Second—and this is the important part—instead of

```
App.Views.MyView.prototype.initialize()
```

you should simply use the CoffeeScript keyword

```
super
```

That effectively does the same thing, but also ensures that the function is called in the correct context. Bonus: It also passes in all of your function arguments for you.

If you're curious, `super` here compiles into

```
initialize.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments)
```

(where `__super__` is a reference to the superclass that's set by both CoffeeScript's `extends`). Read about `apply` [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: I was wondering about extend() and extends and I had also mucked around with super. Maybe I was doing something wrong with it. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

My coffe script isnt so hot but can you call the function sending the view you want to be the value for this in as the first parameter

I suppose in standardish js

```
 var view = null;
 MyView = View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
    // do config stuff then init prototype
     App.Views.MyView.prototype.initialize.call(view)
    }
 })
 view = new MyView;
```

Im not sure what you have access to at that point or the generated js either.
The point being if you have access to what should be the value for this when you call the function you should be able to pass it in.

I would check myself but i don't comprehend coffeescript :)